# Optimizing Code for Efficiently Searching Substrings and Creating a New DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame (df_tp) with columns 'Column1' and 'Column2'. My objective is to iterate through this DataFrame and search for substrings from a list (unit_list) within the values of 'Column2'. When a match is found, I want to create a new DataFrame (save_df) containing the original index and the corresponding value from 'Column2'.

Here is the code I've implemented:

---

```py
# Create a new DataFrame with 'Column1' and 'Column2' as the column headers
save_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Column1', 'Column2'])

# Initialize an index for adding rows to the new DataFrame
index = 0

# Iterate over the rows of the existing DataFrame 'df_tp'
for i, value in df_tp.iterrows():

    # Iterate over the items in the list 'unit_list'
    for unit in unit_list:  

        # Check if the 'unit' is a substring of the string representation of the value in 'Column2'
        if unit in str(value['Column2']):
            save_df.loc[index] = [i, value['Column2']]
            index += 1
            break
```

---

[image: Picture of Dataset]

---

However, I suspect this code might not be the most efficient way to achieve my goal, especially with larger datasets and longer unit_list. It seems to be iterating through each row and then iterating through each item in unit_list for string comparison, which could be computationally expensive.

I'm seeking advice on how to optimize this code to make it more efficient. Is there a better approach or any pandas functionality that can streamline this substring search and row creation process?

Any suggestions or alternative implementations using vectorized operations or optimized methods in pandas would be greatly appreciated. ***Thank you!***

Comment: Please read and edit your question with formatted text instead of the image : [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: what do you mean, how should I insert an image of my dataset

Comment: Text. Stackoverflow allows you to format text, including as a table. It's all in the link I provided for you. Please read it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with joined list by `|` for regex `or`:

```
out = (df.loc[df['Column2'].str.contains('|'.join(unit_list)), 'Column2']
         .reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Column1'}))
```

Or use list comprehension:

```
out = pd.DataFrame([(k, v) for k, v in df['Column2'].items() 
                    for item in unit_list if item in str(v)],
                   columns=['Column1', 'Column2'])
```